# Valgrind error: Invalid read of size 1 disappears when switching to different variable declaration

Tags: c, valgrind, strcmp

I have a while loop which reads stdin until it gets an empty line. It looks like this:

```
while (strcmp((fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin)), "\n") != 0)
{
    process_line(line, option);
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

When I have `line` initialized as:

```
char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
line[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
```

I get this error from Valgrind:

```
==2562== Invalid read of size 1
==2562==    at 0x483FED4: strcmp (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2562==    by 0x10A1E0: main (in /mnt/c/Users/...)
==2562==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

However, if I change the above initialization to this:

```
char *line = "";
```

I get no error.

Could someone please explain it in a way a first-year student can understand? Thank you.

And if it makes any difference, I'm using WSL on Windows 10.

Comment: `strcmp((fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin)), "\n")`?!?!  Have you tested how well that works, err, blows up when you read end-of-file?  Who is teaching you to cram all that into the `while()` statement?  Whoever it is just taught you how to create a fatal bug.  Cramming as much code as you can into a single line like that is a **BAD** idea.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tested it a bunch. It works perfectly fine. The documentation [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) says that it's alright. I'm reading from stdin so there shouldn't be many issues. But I will keep that in mind for when I'm using it on a file.

Comment: The valgrind error is a null pointer dereference (`Address 0x0`).  Apparently a null pointer was passed to `strcmp`.  Which is exactly what will happen if `fgets` should fail - you must test and handle that case before passing the result to `strcmp`.

Comment: The `char *line = "";` is worse as it points to a string which is not writable and also too short.  It causes undefined behavior, of which one possibility is "appearing to work for now".  In C you cannot safely take "I get no error" as evidence for "it is correct".

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm only using the `line` variable in that one place. Would it better if I didn't make it point anywhere? But then I get a warning from gcc.

Comment: @GergelyTóth: No, it must point somewhere.  `fgets` writes the string into the memory that `line` is pointing to, so it has to be pointing to somewhere that `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` bytes of writable memory are located.  Otherwise you again have undefined behavior.

Comment: @GergelyTóth *I tested it a bunch. It works perfectly fine.*  A `NULL` pointer dereference is a strange definition of "works perfectly fine".

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. So that's how it works. Thank you very much. I think my posted answer should be correct then.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error I was getting was not related to variable declaration. I did not check the return value of the `fgets()` function as the commenters pointed out. The following code works for my needs:

```
char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
line[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
while (fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin) != NULL &&
       strcmp(line, "\n") != 0)
{
    process_line(line, option);
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

I don't get any errors for this from Valgrind and gcc. I also tested it in some scenarios and it appears to be working properly.

The usage here is also in line with the code snippet from [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) page.

Comment: Note that doing `line[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';` doesn't accomplish anything; `fgets` ignores the previous contents of the buffer.  And in general, there's no particular value in putting a null terminator near the end of a buffer that is otherwise full of uninitialized garbage; any code that was to read that garbage would still be causing undefined behavior.  If you wanted it to be treated as an empty string, you would put the null byte at the beginning: `line[0] = '\0';` - but that is likewise unnecessary here.

Comment: Also, unless you have a special reason for leaving one extra byte of space in the buffer, you can pass `BUFFER_SIZE` as the size to `fgets` instead of `BUFFER_SIZE - 1`.  The `fgets` function will only store a total of `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes including the null terminator, so there will not be an overflow.